# Quiero modificar la sección about para que el contenido se cargue dinámicamente

Tags: nodejs, mvc, ejs

Perdón, soy nuevo en esto y llevo unas cuantas horas tratando de entender que estoy haciendo mal, pero me sigue apareciendo el error "nosotros is not defined"

en el controller:

```js
sobreNosotros: (req, res) => {
      const nosotros = {
        titulo: 'Sobre nosotros',
        descripcion:'Empresa dedicada a la elaboración de platos de comida italiana, con una amplia gama de productos para toda la familia.'
      };

      res.render('index', { nosotros });
    },
```

en el router:

```js
router.get('/#about', mainController.sobreNosotros);
```

y en el EJS:

```html
<h1 class="ps-center"><%= nosotros.titulo%></h1>
```

*La sección about está dentro del index.

Si alguien me tira una mano, se lo agradeceré mucho!

Answer (score 0):

¿Te da algún error?

Asegúrate que tienes node_modules con las dependencias de tu package.json.

También revisa si tienes el servidor con la configuración correcta para utilizar EJS.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

EJS es para paginas enteras, creo entender que no se puede utilizar para secciones de una pagina, entonces lo que te interesaría sería crear una API que tu pagina haga consultas a tu API y cambie los datos dinámicamente.

Diría que tu ruta no deberia llevar un #.

Es decir tu tienes:

```
router.get('/#about', mainController.sobreNosotros);
```

Y deberías tener:

```
router.get('/about', mainController.sobreNosotros);
```

Te dejo un par de ejemplos a ver si encuentras diferencias a tu proyecto.

[Tutorial de EJS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application-es)

[Get started](https://ejs.co/#install)

Comment: Gracias Klau! dependencias y settings estaba ok. Meti el objeto "nosotros" dentro de la constante index, borre la ruta "about" y quedó andadno! Gracias por tu ayuda. Me guardo esos enlaces que me interesan. Saludos